# Strain Gauge - Wheatstone bridge DRIFT

Tags: temperature, instrumentation-amplifier, wheatstone-bridge, strain-gage

[image]I have a 350 ohm bridge with 04 fixed resistors, later on one of them will be replaced by a strain gauge sensor. In the meantime I am trying to understand where the drift is coming from.

This bridge is connected to an in-amp with 1000x gain.
In order to calibrate the bridge and unbalance it (so I can have, say 1V output at the in-amp output) generally I use a very high resistor (around 500k ohms) in parallel with one of the resistors on the bridge.
These 350 resistors are 0.02% tolerance and 0.2ppm/C. The opamp is a AD8571 (extremely low drift and offset).

Unfortunately I have been struggling for months with a drift that shows in several different ways:

1. Temperature - Only by blowing some hot air briefly, the output varies +/-10mV
2. When the voltage output is increased by any external factor that is removed afterwards, it never goes back to its initial value
3. There is a voltage drift without any temperature change, I managed to have a very precise temperature sensor mounted on the top of the circuit to confirm.

All components are very high quality, spec'd for this particular application, low drift, low offset and really expensive. I do not know whatelse  I can do to get rid of this annoying drift, unpredictability and lack of repeatability.

Comment: What is your excitation voltage?  Are you exceeding some max current spec?

Comment: That means the input varies by +/-10uV, right? (given 1000x gain). So, 0.2ppm/C * (guessing, you don't tell us) 5V excitation * (say) 10C = 10uV on the input ... isn't this drift exactly what you expect, or am I missing something?

Comment: Excitation voltage is 5V. The variation at the input given the temperature drift is correct so the question is, how to get rid of it since the lowest TC I found is 0.2ppm/C ?
The feedback resistor is 200k ohm

One more thing: When I force a heating up situation (from 25 to 45C with a hot air gun) it increase the output voltage but when the temperature goes back to its original value, the output voltage is still offset by a certain amount that never decrease.

Comment: An AD8571 is not an InAmp so what are you using? What generates the 5V also? Show your circuit!

Comment: The AD8571 inamp needs a feedback configuration to have its gain set. I am using a power supply to generate the 5V. So I have a 200k from out to IN- and same 200k from IN+ to GND

Comment: I have uploaded a picture. R5, E6 and RFB are the same part number. Regarding to hot air gun, I blow air from 2m away from the circuit so it takes a good amount to time to warm up. On the top of that, the voltage drifts proportionally to the temperature when it is rising but it shows some sort of hysteresis when it is cooling down. When the temperature is equal to room again, say 20C, the voltage is considerably above it was before this heating cycle and remains at this value forever.

Comment: Given your test method, this may be difficult, but can you think of a way to heat the bridge, amplifier, and power supply one at at time?  Also, I understand you are unbalancing the bridge for test purposes.  Did you trim it to start with?  I mean without the test resistor, do you get 0V?  If not, what is the value without R5 included?

Comment: How does the op-amp (not an InAmp, as I keep saying) connect to the bridge?

Comment: Hi @Andyaka, the opamp is connected to the bridge directly on the PCB.

Comment: Then why is your circuit diagram not showing how the op-amp connects?

Answer (score 1):

You may be seeing thermal EMFs, as well as thermal drift of the resistors.

Blowing hot air with a hot air gun is **not** the way to test a circuit like that. Use a proper environmental chamber with a fan inside and control the air flow over the board (maybe with a bit of foam). You may have to wait an hour or two for the temperature to stabilize. The hot air gun will lead to wrong conclusions. You may see dynamic changes that even out as the gradients disappear.

Do not have anything on the board that dissipates a lot of power (I assume you are doing this).

Leaded resistors can be a bit less prone to change from external mechanical forces. Try flexing the board a bit and see if your reading changes. Chances are this is not your problem, but it's worth a check.

Comment: It changes a little bit of the output voltage, it sits on a higher value and does not seem to go back. What on earth am I missing here? After so many years in the design industry, this is the first time I come across this issue.

Comment: Did you assemble the board yourself? How was it cleaned? 350 ohms is not a high impedance, but leakage of 50M would cause the effects you see. No clean flux is a particular problem.

Comment: Truth been said, I have not taken any further care regarding to cleaning the board. I populated the SMD components myself and due to it is a testing subject, components are replaced very often.

Comment: Check the solder you are using, this can be a tough problem to solve.

Comment: Should I ship the board to Toronto ? =) Dear Spehro, any solder you may recommend?

Comment: Well, I could probably fix it, but before you give up- Kester 44 eutectic.

Comment: @Spehro said, "Try flexing the board a bit and see if your reading changes." This was my first thought, also. Expansion of the PCB's substrate material, and therefore of the PCB's traces, might be a place to start looking. Have you tried using thicker trace widths for the bridge circuit and the signal paths into the instrumentation amplifier to mitigate changes to the traces' cross sectional areas due to thermal expansion/contraction. Also, have you tried multiple heating/cooling cycles to "break in" the board, to see if that improves the board's repeatability?

Comment: @JimFischer It sounds like he's using Vishay Z-foil resistors which cost like $25 each and are very, very good, so I tend to discount that possibility.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany / JimFischer Yes, I am using Vishay foil resistors. Usually 0.02% tolerance and 0.2ppm/C. The 200k resistors are not rated the same so they could be causing this annoying drift and hysteresis. Will try applying your recommendations to the design and see how it goes. Thank you so much for your help.